# How to remove item in list in list with list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I have a large list like this:

```
mylist = [['pears','apples','40'],['grapes','trees','90','bears']]
```

I'm trying to remove all numbers within the lists of this list. So I made a list of numbers as strings from 1 to 100:

```
def integers(a, b):
         return list(range(a, b+1))

numb = integers(1,100)

numbs = []
for i in range(len(numb)):
    numbs.append(str(numb[i])) # strings

numbs = ['1','2',....'100']
```

How can I iterate through lists in `mylist` and remove the numbers in `numbs`? Can I use list comprehension in this case?

Comment: is always the last element the number?

Comment: @Daniel No thats not always the case

Comment: to remove ALL numbers or just those from `numb` range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mylist = [[item for item in sublist if item not in numbs] for sublist in mylist]` should do the trick.

However, this isn't *quite* what you've asked. Nothing was actually removed from `mylist`, we've just built an entirely new list and reassigned it to `mylist`. Same logical result, though.

Answer (score 1):

If number is always in the end in sublist

```
mylist = [ x[:-1] for x in mylist ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If numbers are always at the end and only once, you can remove the last item like:

```
my_new_list = [x[:-1] for x in mylist]
```

If there is more (of if they are not ordered), you have to loop thru each elements, in that case you can use:

```
my_new_list = [[elem for elem in x if elem not in integer_list] for x in mylist]
```

I would also recommend to generate the list of interger as follow :

```
integer_list = list(map(str, range(1, 100)))
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enumerating all the integers you want to filter out you can use the `isdigit` to test each string to see if it really is only numbers:

```
mylist = [['pears','apples','40'],['grapes','trees','90','bears']]
mylist2 = [[x for x in aList if not x.isdigit()] for aList in mylist]
print mylist2
[['pears', 'apples'], ['grapes', 'trees', 'bears']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following list:

```
mylist = [['pears','apples','40'],['grapes','trees','90','bears']]
numbs = [str(i) for i in range(1, 100)]
```

Using list comprehension to remove element in `numbs`

```
[[l for l in ls if l not in numbs] for ls in mylist]
```

This is a more general way to remove digit elements in a list

```
[[l for l in ls if not l.isdigit()] for ls in mylist]
```

Comment: In Python 3 `range` is an object, so you don't need to create a list, you can check for containment directly and efficiently.

Comment: @PeterWood Can you show me an example? I'm curious.

Comment: Just read the documentation: [**`range`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)